# Get Recipients from Outlook.MailItem

Tags: c#, .net, email, outlook, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook addin where I'm trying to get the email addresses when composing an email. When typing the addresses in the "To" field, if they are underlined then the addin reads all recipients properly. However if it's a new email address, ie. it won't be underlined, then that email address is not present in the Recipients list, here's my code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem email = GetMailItem(e);
int count = email.Recipients.Count;
```

Comment: Do they become accessible if you tab out of the To edit box first?

Comment: They do, but it's not guaranteed the user will do that before clicking on the addin

Comment: Just trying to narrow down the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `email.Save()` first did the trick

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use the recipients.resolveall method - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867165.aspx

Max

Comment: This doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Strangly I have found that, while calling MailItem.Save() does resolve the Addresses (so that they are present in the MailItem.Recipients collection), calling MailItem.Save() more than once (3-4 times) risks the following exception:"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040109): The operation cannot be performed because the message has been changed"

Getting the MailItem.HTMLBody property seems to resolve all valid the email addresses in the To, CC, BCC fields and avoid the risk of calling MailItem.Save() more than once.

I have personally found that MailItem.ResolveAll() simply clears any unresolved new Recipients added after the MailItem.Save() was last called.